# How can I set OnClickListener to two buttons in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In my android app I have one activity to show a RecyclerView in which each row is composed by a TextView and 2 buttons. Just like that:

[image: ListAdapter Layout]

Well, following many explanations of internet I have made this Adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    protected Vector<List> lists;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, Vector lists) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.lists = lists;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List list = lists.elementAt(position);
        holder.name.setText(list.getName());
        //holder.delete.set HOW DO I GET BUTTON HERE?
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lists.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView name;
        public Button edit;
        public Button delete;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listname);
            edit = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.edit:
                    break;
                case R.id.delete:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't found examples of having 2 buttons (there are only examples of adding images) in each view of the recyclerview, as in the first image. I mean, guess I have 10 List elements in my RecyclerView, how can I have in each of them to one side a TextView with the name of the List and 2 buttons and handle clickListener?. As in the following image, which I have done by hand for you to see what I am talking about:

[image]

This is the activity that will show the recyclerView; don't take it into account because I am pretty sure the way is wrong. I get lists information from sqlite database:

```
public class ShowListOfLists extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_list_of_lists);
    LocalDB localDB = new LocalDB(this, "localBD", null, 1);
    Vector <List> ListAdapter = localDB.getAllPrivateList();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewlistas);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, ListAdapter));
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

A list have the following attributes:

```
-idList int
-name String
-Description String
-creationDate Date
-active int (0 or 1)
-deactivationDate Date
```

Thank you in advance.

/*******************************EDIT****************************************/

Thank to you I have been able to show the recyclerView and it works well. But I see that:

[image: recyclerviewresult]

Instead of that:

[image]

This the XML code and design of the adapter:

[image: ListAdapter Layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bg"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="Delete"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="Edit"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the XML of the recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pc.kanayel.runoutof.ShowListOfLists"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerviewlistas">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: You can see my code , its very simple you can do the same.

Comment: For your second issue about the width, see my edit.

Comment: Really thank you! You totally saved my app, I couldn't have finished it without your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to add some code to your `ListAdapter`. It is there, where you have to implement `onClickListener`. The code for your case should look something like the one below.

You can pass any parameter you need to. It depends on the functionality you want to achieve. Here I have demonstrated passing the order of item clicked inside of list.

**Option 1 (power/performance efficient)**

So, what does the code below actually mean? You have already created a `ViewHolder` and implemented `OnClickListener`. That is correct. Now you need to set `OnClickListener` to two buttons. But what these buttons will do when clicked is defined by the `interface` we created inside of `ViewHolder`.

When app will run `RecyclerView` will create as many ViewHolders as it is needs to fill the available screen with list items by calling `onCreateViewHolder()` method for each of viewholders. When you scroll up/down these `ViewHolders` will be reused. `OnCreateViewHolder()` is not called, only `onBindViewHolder()` is called to update the content of viewholder. The code below made so that, when ViewHolder is created it will also create an `MyClickListener` that will be used by `OnClickListener` of viewholder and when viewholder is reused it will not create new `OnClickListener`. It means that our method is performance efficient.

**Option 2 (not efficient)**

You could also `setOnClickListener()` inside of `onBindViewHolder()`. However, as I have mentioned in the paragraph above, this method is called every time you scroll to update the content of viewholder. Now it would create new `OnClickListener` object everytime. While **Option 1** has `OnClickListener` on every ViewHolder and it reuses them.

**Code for Option 1**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    protected Vector<List> lists;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, Vector lists) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.lists = lists;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view, new MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEdit(int p) {
                // Implement your functionality for onEdit here
            }

            @Override
            public void onDelete(int p) {
                // Implement your functionality for onDelete here
            }
        });
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List list = lists.elementAt(position);
        holder.name.setText(list.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lists.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        MyClickListener listener;

        TextView name;
        Button edit;
        Button delete;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, MyClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listname);
            edit = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            this.listener = listener;

            edit.setOnClickListener(this);
            delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.edit:
                    listener.onEdit(this.getLayoutPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.delete:
                    listener.onDelete(this.getLayoutPosition());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
            void onEdit(int p);
            void onDelete(int p);
    }
}
```

**Edit for your second question**

To make list items take all the width set the `width` of your `recyclerview` to `match_parent`. It is also better to make it a child view of some layout. For instance as given below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pc.kanayel.runoutof.ShowListOfLists">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewlistas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout>
```

**And** change this code inside of your adapter:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter, null);
```

to this:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter, parent, false);
```

Comment: Such a nice answer!  But what about class ShowListofLists? Is that the way to show the recycled view or not? And is that method correctly implemented?                                                                     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List list = lists.elementAt(position);
        holder.name.setText(list.getName());
    }

Comment: `ShowListOfLists` is an `Activity` because it extends the `AppCompatActivity`. It controls the UI. So the `ListAdapter` is the tool which will be used by `Activity`. So your implementation of `ShowListOfLists` seems to be right. It is there where you declare recyclerview , create adapter and set it to recyclerview.

Comment: @Kanayel if you are going to use the method in my answer and think it is good, then please, consider accepting it.

Comment: Sorry I am new in stack overflow and I dont manage it as good as I like. I think I already accepted it. If not, just let me know

Comment: @Marat The Code for Option 1 gives me an error `Inner classes cannot have static declarations`. Also, inside of `onCreateViewHolder` you are passing  `v` as first argument, what is that? I don't see a `v` declared anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List list = lists.elementAt(position);
        holder.name.setText(list.getName());
        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Do your stuff
                }
            });
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Do your stuff
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you toodude, but I'll use the first option of Marat because I have to take into account the efficiency