# Adding multiple OnClickListeners to a RecyclerView using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm in the process of fiddling my way to a working app using Kotlin and I have hit a roadblock when trying to implement OnClickListeners for my three buttons. I have my RecyclerView populate properly, but despite following the recommendations on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474333/how-can-i-set-onclicklistener-to-two-buttons-in-recyclerview/45474550) (except in Kotlin) and following [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), though I am still having trouble getting the implementation to work.

The code below is my adapter class for the implementation.

```
class BrowseHabitsAdapter(private val habits: ArrayList<Habit>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BrowseHabitsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.habit_card, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(itemView, object: HabitClickListener {
            override fun onDecrease(position: Int) {
                val streak = itemView.dayCounter.text.toString().toInt()
                itemView.dayCounter.text = streak.dec().toString()
            }

            override fun onIncrease(position: Int) {
                val streak = itemView.dayCounter.text.toString().toInt()
                itemView.dayCounter.text = streak.inc().toString()
            }

            override fun onEdit(position: Int) {
                TODO("Change Activity to Edit")
            }
        })


    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = habits[position]

        holder.habitTitle.text = currentItem.title
        holder.streak.text = currentItem.streak.toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = habits.size


    class ViewHolder(itemView : View, listener : HabitClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        val habitTitle: TextView = itemView.habitTitle
        val streak: TextView = itemView.dayCounter
        val decreaseCounterButton : Button = itemView.decreaseCounterButton
        val increaseCounterButton : Button = itemView.increaseCounterButton
        val listener = listener

        init {
            decreaseCounterButton.setOnClickListener(this)
            increaseCounterButton.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            when (itemView.id) {
                itemView.decreaseCounterButton.id -> listener.onDecrease(this.layoutPosition)
                itemView.increaseCounterButton.id -> listener.onIncrease(this.layoutPosition)
            }
        }
    }

    interface HabitClickListener {
        fun onDecrease(position : Int)
        fun onIncrease(position : Int)
        fun onEdit(position : Int)
    }
}
```

and the following is my XML code defining one of my cards:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/habitTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/default_card_title"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settingsIcon"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardControls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/decreaseCounterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dayCounter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/increaseCounterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Any additional explanation that can be provided as to what I did wrong and what is going on in detail would be really appreciated!

Comment: what issue occur?

Comment: what are you expect and what is the issue?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Sorry, I thought I specified. My OnClickListeners do not seem to be attaching properly. Despite no errors, the button clicks have nothing change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in kotlin so need to implement `View.OnClickListener` you can directly use `setOnClickListener` on any view.

Inside your ViewHolder Class:

```
itemView.increaseCounterButton.setOnClickListener{

       listener.onIncrease(this.layoutPosition)
 }       

itemView.decreaseCounterButton.setOnClickListener{

      listener.onDecrease(this.layoutPosition)
 }
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! Can you elaborate on the reason that you put the argument in curly braces? As far as I know `setOnClickListener` is a method so it should be taking a parameter only? I also notice in IntelliJ it lists `it: View!` next to the curly braces, I'm assuming this is the "type" of sorts, but I am not familiar with it? Could you maybe explain it a little more :)?

Comment: I didn't pass as a parameter it's lambda version of setOnClickListener check this link https://antonioleiva.com/lambdas-kotlin-android/ you will understand

Answer (score 0):

It should be `view?.id` instead of `itemView.id`

```
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            when (v?.id) {
                itemView.decreaseCounterButton.id -> listener.onDecrease(this.layoutPosition)
                itemView.increaseCounterButton.id -> listener.onIncrease(this.layoutPosition)
            }
        }
```

Additionally, your code with bugs. You handle `HabitClickListener` only update UI, when you scroll your data will be update base on `habits`. It means it will be revert when you scroll. Make sure `streak` of model `Habit` is `var`

```
        return ViewHolder(itemView, object: HabitClickListener {
            override fun onDecrease(position: Int) {
                habits[position].streak = habits[position].streak.dec()
                itemView.dayCounter.text = shabits[position].streak.toString()
            }

            override fun onIncrease(position: Int) {
                habits[position].streak = habits[position].streak.inc()
                itemView.dayCounter.text = shabits[position].streak.toString()
            }

            override fun onEdit(position: Int) {
                TODO("Change Activity to Edit")
            }
        })
```